# nginx lua block exception

Tags: lua, nginx-reverse-proxy

I tried make a dynamic reverse proxying via python and Nginx-Lua

However, I've never used Lua before, Hence I can't be sure why the problem is caused.

seems following error message on err.log file:

> failed to load inlined Lua code: access_by_lua(nginx.conf:44):4: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 2) near '=', client: 127.0.0.1

and my conf file codes as following:

```
  set $datax '';
  set $res '';

  access_by_lua '
    content_by_lua_block {
    ngx.req.read_body();
    ngx.var.datax = ngx.req.get_body_data();
    ngx.var.res = os.execute("/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.py ngx.var.datax");

    if ngx.var.res == "VIP" then
            proxy_pass  https://mail.xxx.com;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
    else
            proxy_pass  https://mail2.xxx.com;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
    end
  }';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is malformed, you try to use `content_by_lua_block` inside of `access_by_lua`.
Take a look a the docs: [content_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#content_by_lua_block), [access_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#access_by_lua)

I would recommend you to use `content_by_lua_block`, after `access_by_lua` is discouraged with release `v0.9.17`.

```lua
set $datax '';
set $res '';

content_by_lua_block {
  [your lua code]
}
```